# Help with summing characters

Tags: number-theory, summation, quadratic-residues, gauss-sums, jacobi-sums

Let $p \equiv 1(n)$. Let $\chi$ denote a character from $\mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Then, in Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Number Theory*, while trying to find the number of solutions to $X^n+Y^n=1$, the authors claim that if $-1$ is a $n^{th}$ power, the sum $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\chi^j(-1)$ is $n$, and $0$ otherwise. I'm not sure why this follows?

**My work so far:**

In the case that $-1$ isn't an $n^{th}$ power, I am guessing that the sum is zero as $\chi^j(-1)$ must be a $p-1^{th}$ root of unity and then as $n \mid p-1$, the sum of all roots of unity is $0$.

If $-1$ is an $n^{th}$ power, then there exists some $a$ such that $a^n \equiv -1 \mod p$ (is this what it means?). Then,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\chi^{j}(-1)&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\chi^j(a^n)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\chi^j(a)^n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\chi^{jn}(a) \ldots
\end{align*}

and then I do not how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much!

**Edit:** In response to comments, I have attached the relevant screenshots below:
[image: Definition of character]

and
[image: Claim in textbook]

Comment: I think what your problem is not quite correct. Consider $p = 7$ and $n = 2$. Then $-1$ is not a square. Now if you take the character $\Bbb{F}_7 \to \Bbb{C}^\times$ defined by $a \mapsto \zeta_7^a$. Then clearly $1 + \zeta_7^{-1} \ne 0$.

Comment: @Offlaw I have attached pictures from the textbook as well. I see your point, but that is what the textbook says and I have no better explanation :(

Comment: I don't have access to a copy of Ireland & Rosen, but I'm fairly sure that in the formula for $N(x^n+y^n=1)$ the character $\chi$ is assumed to have order $n$. Implying that $n\mid p-1$. In that case $\chi(-1)=1$, if $-1$ is an $n$th power and something else, if it isn't. In both cases the sum $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\chi^j(-1)$ is a geometric sum, and the claim is trivial (or, if you prefer, an instance of orthogonality relations). **Please check!**

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, you're absolutely right, the character does have order $n$! I don't know how i missed it. It then does easily follow that the sum is $n$ when $-1$ is a $n^{th}$ power. I am embarrassed to admit that I am still struggling with the other case? I don't know the character relations yet. However, if $\chi(-1)=x$, then using the GP formula, the sum is $(x^{n-1}-1)/(x-1)=x^{n-2}+\ldots+x+1$. I don't know what makes this 0?

Comment: An "off-by-one error" right there. If $\chi(-1)=x$, then (assuming $x\neq1$)
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\chi(-1)^j=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x^j=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}.$$

Comment: Okay, ooops, missed that. Thank you SO SO much @JyrkiLahtonen!!